# Como leer y escribir valores en una base de datos JSON para cambiar valores en el html con un script (JS) - Node JS

Tags: javascript, html, json, nodejs, aplicación-web

Estoy creando una web con Node JS, y me gustaría poder leer valores de una base de datos JSON para mostrar los valores en el html y mas tarde escribir valores.

¿Cuál es la mejor forma de hacer esto?
He estado buscando y he encontrado infinidad de frameworks, paquetes y opciones, pero realmente no veo nada concluyente.

Comment: lo que buscas es algo parecido a una realtime database de firebase, te aconsejo tres cosas entonces: 1.) pasar por el [tour] por ser nuevo usuario, 2.) leer [ask] para aprender como funciona el sitio y porque tu pregunta no es valida para una respuesta, 3.) deberias usar firebase, ya que usa una base de datos no relacional en tiempo real y que se asemeja mas a la forma en como se almacenaria la informacion de un JSON.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Lamentablemente tu pregunta es totalmente basada en opiniones. Saludos

Comment: Vaya, coordinados al mismo tiempo!, wau.